# How to use Excel Application.NormDist formula in Go language?

Tags: excel, go

I recently encountered the need to migrate an old application written in Excel to Go language. The application relies on the Application.NormDist function for calculating values.

```vb
=Application.NORMDIST(A1,A3,A4,TRUE)
```

However, I couldn't find any Go library that provides this function, and crafting my own function poses challenges with no assurance of correctness.

Could anyone suggest a solution or guide me on how to handle the conversion of the NormDist function from Excel to Go?

Comment: "I couldn't find any Go library that provides this function" This sounds suspicious as even math/rand contains this.

Comment: Hello @Volker, the `Application.NORMDIST` in excel take 4 arguments (x, mean, standard_dev, cumulative) for calculate https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/normdist-hàm-normdist-126db625-c53e-4591-9a22-c9ff422d6d58
And It look not the same with `NormFloat64` in `math/rand` package

Comment: Did you read the documentation of math/rand.NormFloat64 at all? Well, there are things called math books. I'd urge you to consult one. The most basic introductory formulary in statistics will do.

Comment: Yahh... Actually, I'm quite lacking expertise in this field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was create a function, that use distuv package for calculate Cumulative distribution function (CDF) and Probability mass function (Prod) follow this guide of Microsoft https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/office/normdist-function-126db625-c53e-4591-9a22-c9ff422d6d58

```
func NORMDIST(x float64, mean float64, stdDeviation float64, cumulative bool) (float64, error) {
    if stdDeviation <= 0 {
        return 0, ErrInvalidStdDev
    }

    if mean == 0 && stdDeviation == 1 && cumulative {
        stdNormalDist := distuv.UnitNormal
        return stdNormalDist.CDF(x), nil
    }

    dist := distuv.Normal{
        Mu:    mean,
        Sigma: stdDeviation,
    }

    if cumulative {
        return dist.CDF(x), nil
    }

    return dist.Prob(x), nil
}
```